# Свой Behavior для View внутри Toolbar в CoordinatorLayout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, coordinator-layout

Недавно начал изучать `CoordinatorLayout` и решил написать свой Behavior.

Цель такая: при прокрутке вниз, `ImageView`, стоящий посередине `Toolbar`-а, должен плавно переместиться к краю экрана или тубара.

Помогите, как можно реализовать плавный переход к краю `Toolbar`. Пытался сделать что-то типа view.setX(view.getX() - 3), но это не получается (и не получится) - то не доходит до края, то проходит через край.

Comment: Посмотрите вот тут https://habr.com/post/270121/

Comment: @Serj Да я читал. Там написано как реализовать behavior но не то что делать с вью когда ты прослушиваешь